# Does npm install always get the latest *compatible* version of a dependency?

Tags: npm, npm-install, dependency-management, package.json, semantic-versioning

After reading the [documentation,](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-install) I still don't have a clear idea about this.

Let's say I specify

`"dependencies": {"some_package": ^3.1.1}`

in my `package.json`, and the latest compatible (i.e. consistent with the semantic versioning declared above) version of `some_package` is actually `3.4.9`. If I were to  run `npm install`, would that automatically install version `3.4.9`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [the `npm semver calculator`](https://semver.npmjs.com/) to determine what version will be installed. Where it says to enter a range, enter `^3.1.1`. Since I don't know what `some_package` is, I can't check myself, but you can.

To understand ranges that start with a caret (`^`), read [the `semver` doc](https://semver.npmjs.com/). Caret means "install the most recent version that doesn't change the left-most non-zero digit". So `^3.1.1` means "install the latest 3.x version". So, yes, it will install `3.4.9` or later if they are available.